# String into array (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string of integers

```
str = "[7,2,7,7,2,7,7,4,3,2]"
```

and i want to get an array so that i can manipulate the data easily, but i have no idea how to do it. Can you help me ? I'm sure it's a basic task but i am not very familiar with node.

Thank you.

Comment: `JSON.parse("[7,2,7,7,2,7,7,4,3,2]")`

Answer (score 1):

Try `JSON.parse(yourStr)`. Alternately:

```
yourString.substr(1,arr.length-2).split(",").map((el) => { 
  return parseInt(el) 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like JSON, parse it with JSON.parse

```
numbers = JSON.parse("[7,2,7,7,2,7,7,4,3,2]")
```